# Is it possible to connect to infura using a standalone executable?

Tags: metamask, wallets, json-rpc, infura

New to eth dev here, so trying to figure out what's currently possible.

Can an HTTP response contain the wallet information required to run a contract on the ethereum blockchain?

I am making a standalone desktop app and I want to prompt users to sign in to their metamask account. The app will minimize and make an HTTP request causing metamask to pop up in a browser window. After authenticating with MM, the HTTP response will trigger the app to regain focus and proceed with contract transactions. Can the HTTP response contain the wallet information needed to connect to an infura node and make a transaction?

Comment: did you check out the docs of this integration on Metamask's website?

Comment: You will need the desktop app to run some kind of service that communicate with the page.

Comment: @Nulik I didn't find anything, could you point me to a link?